# How to write that path in string to be parsed - Twig

Tags: twig

I set links in this way in twig:

```
{% set link = '<a href="">('~product.price~)'~product.name~'</a>' %}
```

The problem is how to fill the link

```
{% set link = '<a href="'~{{ path('restaurant') }}~'">('~product.price~)'~product.name~'</a>' %}
```

This gives me the error: `A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{"`

```
{% set link = '<a href="{ path('restaurant') }}">('~product.price~)'~product.name~'</a>' %}
```

`Unexpected token "name" of value "restaurant" ("end of statement block" expected)`

can you please help me :(

The link will also have an id argument.

The only thing I can think of is writing a filter which takes te id as argument and replaces the empty link, but I'm not quite sure it will work, and it doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: Well if anything, you don not have to use parentheses within `{% %}` blocks

Comment: Thank you very much! `{% set link = '<a href="'~path('restaurant')~'">'~product.name~'</a>' %}` works! You can write an answer if you want, so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use parentheses within `{% %}` blocks.

Furthermore, unless you have a specific reason for putting the whole markup for the link in a variable, you might want to consider creating links like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('restaurant') }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
```